# How can I debug problems with move_uploaded_file?

Tags: php, upload

I have a form like

```
<form action="send.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div>
        <label for="subject">Subject</label>
        <input type="text" name="subject" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="image">Image</label>
        <input type="file" name="image" />
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Send" />
</form>
```

PHP like

```
echo '<pre>'; print_r($_FILES); echo '</pre>';
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], 'images/' . $_FILES['image']['name'])) {
    echo 'ok';
} else {
    echo 'error!';
};
```

I keep getting `error` the print_r looks like

```
Array
(
    [image] => Array
        (
            [name] => Untitled-1.jpg
            [type] => image/jpeg
            [tmp_name] => /tmp/phpprWdjN
            [error] => 0
            [size] => 61768
        )

)
```

Comment: My guess would be you dont have permission to write to `images/` folder. Or, that `Untitled-1.jpg` already exists, and you dont have permission to overwrite it.

Comment: @webdestroya, agree. or you don't have the directory named 'images'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Activate [error reporting](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php), then you should see the error thrown by `move_uploaded_file` telling you what's wrong.

Answer (score 4):

Your $_FILES looks file, error=0 means the upload completed successfully. Most likely it's a permissions error. You can try doing something like:

```
if (!is_writeable('images/' . $_FILES['image']['name'])) {
   die("Cannot write to destination file");
}
```

However, be aware that you're using a user-provided filename, so if someone uploads "pwn_my_server.php", your script will write it out to the images directory, and then they can simply visit `yoursite.com/images/pwn_my_server.php` and take control of your site.

In general it is NEVER a good idea to trust anything in the $_FILES array, or use it directly, since the entirety of its contents are under remote user control. The only thing created by the server is the error code and tmp_name. The rest is potentially malicious.

Comment: If you check for `is_writeable('images/' . $_FILES['image']['name'])` before uploading the file, it will always return false.

Answer (score 0):

maybe the problem is 'image/' folder, you can set the absolute path here and make sure that path is writable, then have a try.

Answer (score 0):

Use the code below:
1. create the directory named 'uploads'
2. save the file with .php extension

now run the code.

```
<?php
if (!empty($_FILES))
{
    // PATH TO THE DIRECTORY WHERE FILES UPLOADS
    $file_src   =   'uploads/'.$_FILES['image']['name'];
    // FUNCTION TO UPLOAD THE FILE
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $file_src)):
    // SHOW THE SUCCESS MESSAGE AFTER THE MOVE - NO VISIBLE CHANGE
    echo 'Your file have been uploaded sucessfuly';
    else:
    // SHOW ERROR MESSAGE
    echo 'Error';
    endif;

}
?>
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div>
        <label for="subject">Subject</label>
        <input type="text" name="subject" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="image">Image</label>
        <input type="file" name="image" />
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Send" name='submit' />
</form>
```

:)

Comment: So you're not even checking whether `move_uploaded_file` succeeded...? Well, that's *one* way of fixing an error message... :-/